# Undefined index in Laravel, array created with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4, phpexcel

I Have a dynamic form that creates excel files (PHPExcel Class) and send them via email (SwiftMailer) as attachment.

In my view i create new input/file array blocks with javascript. 1,2,3....15

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).on('ready', function() {

                    //Yeni ürün ekleye tıklandığında, visible olmayan formu visible yap
                    $('.yeniekle').on('click', function() {

                        if( $('#iterable2').css('display') === 'none') {
                            $('#iterable2').css('display', 'block');
                            return;
                        }

                        if( $('#iterable3').css('display') === 'none') {
                            $('#iterable3').css('display', 'block');
                            return;
                        }

                        if( $('#iterable4').css('display') === 'none') {
                            $('#iterable4').css('display', 'block');
                            return;
                        }

                        if( $('#iterable5').css('display') === 'none') {
                            $('#iterable5').css('display', 'block');
                            return;
                        }

                        if( $('#iterable6').css('display') === 'none') {
                            $('#iterable6').css('display', 'block');
                            return;
                        }

                        if( $('#iterable7').css('display') === 'none') {
                            $('#iterable7').css('display', 'block');
                            return;
                        }

                        if( $('#iterable8').css('display') === 'none') {
                            $('#iterable8').css('display', 'block');
                            return;
                        }

                        if( $('#iterable9').css('display') === 'none') {
                            $('#iterable9').css('display', 'block');
                            return;
                        }

                        if( $('#iterable10').css('display') === 'none') {
                            $('#iterable10').css('display', 'block');
                            return;
                        }

                        if( $('#iterable11').css('display') === 'none') {
                            $('#iterable11').css('display', 'block');
                            return;
                        }

                        if( $('#iterable12').css('display') === 'none') {
                            $('#iterable12').css('display', 'block');
                            return;
                        }

                        if( $('#iterable13').css('display') === 'none') {
                            $('#iterable13').css('display', 'block');
                            return;
                        }

                        if( $('#iterable14').css('display') === 'none') {
                            $('#iterable14').css('display', 'block');
                            return;
                        }

                        if( $('#iterable15').css('display') === 'none') {
                            $('#iterable15').css('display', 'block');
                            return;
                        }

                        alert("Sadece 15 tane ek ürün girebilirsiniz!")
                        return false;
                    });

                    $('#btnid2').on('click', function() {
                        $('#iterable2').css('display', 'none');
                    });

                    $('#btnid3').on('click', function() {
                        $('#iterable3').css('display', 'none');
                    });

                    $('#btnid4').on('click', function() {
                        $('#iterable4').css('display', 'none');
                    });

                    $('#btnid5').on('click', function() {
                        $('#iterable5').css('display', 'none');
                    });

                    $('#btnid6').on('click', function() {
                        $('#iterable6').css('display', 'none');
                    });

                    $('#btnid7').on('click', function() {
                        $('#iterable7').css('display', 'none');
                    });

                    $('#btnid8').on('click', function() {
                        $('#iterable8').css('display', 'none');
                    });

                    $('#btnid9').on('click', function() {
                        $('#iterable9').css('display', 'none');
                    });

                    $('#btnid10').on('click', function() {
                        $('#iterable10').css('display', 'none');
                    });

                    $('#btnid11').on('click', function() {
                        $('#iterable11').css('display', 'none');
                    });

                    $('#btnid12').on('click', function() {
                        $('#iterable12').css('display', 'none');
                    });

                    $('#btnid13').on('click', function() {
                        $('#iterable13').css('display', 'none');
                    });

                    $('#btnid14').on('click', function() {
                        $('#iterable14').css('display', 'none');
                    });

                    $('#btnid15').on('click', function() {
                        $('#iterable15').css('display', 'none');
                    });

                });

                </script>
```

everything fine till 7th btn. But if i'll add 8th. Laravel give me a warning

> Undefined index: iterable8_resim
>
> iterable8_resim

is an array and my controller looks like:

```
$currChar2 = 'C'; //Harfler
        $iterableCount = 10; //Excelde kaç basamak atlayacağı
        $satir = 9;
        for($i = 2; $i <= 16; $i++)
        {
            foreach($input["iterable{$i}_resim"] as $k => $v)
            {
                $workbook->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.($satir+1), $input["iterable{$i}_adi"]); 
                $workbook->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('K'.($satir+1), $input["iterable{$i}_adet"]); 
                $workbook->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M'.($satir+1), $input["iterable{$i}_fiyat"]); 
                $workbook->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.($satir+1), $input["iterable{$i}_stok"]); 

                if(is_object($v) === true) //Eğer bir resimse
                {
                    $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
                    $objDrawing->setName("name");
                    $objDrawing->setDescription("Description");
                    $objDrawing->setPath($_FILES["iterable{$i}_resim"]["tmp_name"][$k]);
                    $objDrawing->setCoordinates($currChar2 . $iterableCount);
                    $objDrawing->setHeight(65);
                    $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objWorksheet);


                    $currChar2++;
                    $currChar2++;
                }


             }

             $satir+=4;
             $currChar2='C';
             $iterableCount +=4;
        }
```

Laravel's shows error on

```
{
            foreach($input["iterable{$i}_resim"] as $k => $v)
            {
```

I dont know why am i getting this error. 
Any help will be greatly appricated.

Comment: Did you try `print_r($input)` to check if index 'iterable8_resim' does exist in the output? Can you paste the output here?

Comment: Show us HTML with iterable8 input field.

Comment: `<div class="control-group">  
          <label class="control-label">Resim: </label>
          <div class="controls">
          <input type="file" name="iterable8_resim[]" class="span6 m-wrap">   
          </div>
          </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. It's about php.ini setting

> max_file_uploads

We increase the settings now problem solved.